# WPF set dataGrid witdth to 30% of screen or parent's width

Tags: wpf, datagrid, resize, width, screen

What I want to do is next, I have a MainWindow with 3 dataGrids, whichs are contained in StackPanel, and what I want to do here, I want to resize datagrid width to: for example 30% of screens, because there are 3 datagrids it will be 90% of screen width space, and that is okay because I will use only MainWindow and that dataGrids to present some data. And important is to note that I will use it on different size of monitors/displays.

Here is image of what I am talking about:
[image]

as you can see because I don't have any data in dataGrids they are very narrow. And how could I keep their width on 30% of that stack panel or whatever, with data or not I want dataGrids to stay width 30% of screen.

```
MinWidth=""
```

or something like that?

Thanks guys, Cheers

P.S I tested it on small screen and when I fill dataGrids with data, I can not see third dataGrid at all :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Grid` columns. Width="*n**" means to set the width proportionally: 3 + 3 + 3 + 1 == 10, so in this case a column width of "3*" will be three tenths of the total width. They'll resize appropriately as you stretch the parent.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Grid.Column="0">
    </DataGrid>

    <DataGrid Grid.Column="1">
    </DataGrid>

    <DataGrid Grid.Column="2">
    </DataGrid>

    <!-- You don't need a control to fill the remaining 1* column. -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: I did that mate, and it acctualy works, it separate datagrids on screen and its awesome, but why I can't see my data in grid anymore? before I used:  `datagrid1.ItemsSource = OrdersController.localOrders();` and it worked and now I can't see any data when I run my wpf app. it looks like datagrids are empty..

Comment: @Roxy'Pro My XAML doesn't have names. I didn't bother transcribing all your attributes from your screenshot (I might have bothered if I could have copied text rather than retyping a screenshot). Did you paste in my exact XAML without giving the DataGrids their names?

Comment: I will post full code, I decided for now to leave only one grid, but I will post edit on this post, I have also one more question, thats about how  could I set width of columns/color and width of column header.. so if you could help me about that I would appreciate so much and thanks for answer!

Comment: Are you talking about DataGrid columns? They have Width, MinWidth, and MaxWidth properties for design time. At runtime, get the real current width from the ActualWidth property. If you 're talking about `Grid` columns, they don't have headers, but you can add a row at the top.

Comment: I will post new question mate! and I will message you to check, by the way thanks a lot for this question answer!